# Scraping Contact Information from Several Websites with Python

Tags: python

I want to collect contact information from all county governments. I do not have a list of their websites. I want to do three things with Python: 1) create a list of county government websites, 2) extract names, email addresses, and phone numbers of government officials, and 3) convert URLs and all the contact information into an excel sheet or csv.

I am a beginner in Python, and any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For creating tables, you would use a package called `pandas`

for extracting info from websites, a package called `beautifulsoup4` is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

1. For scraping a website (all data present in the world) you should
   define what type of search you want to start, I mean do you want to
   Search in google or a specific website for both of them you need a
   `request` library to curl a site or query a google (like search in
   the search bar) and got HTML. for parsing data, you have gotten you
   can choose `BEATIFULSOAP`. Both of them have good documents and you
   must read them don't disappoint it's easy.
2. Because the count of countries around the world is more than 170+
   you should manage your data; for managing data I recommend using `pandas`
   and finally, after processing data you can convert data to any type of file
   `pandas.to_excel`, `pandas.to_csv` and more.